# React Router and Express routing

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I am serving a production build index.html of react from an Express server. The react app uses react router for navigating. When using react router, there is a problem that when refreshing the page, it can not get the data anymore because it is sending GET request to http://example.com/abc and that URL is not handled in express. So I found the solution by handling every get request: app.get('*') to redirect back to the home page so the page can get all the resources it need. However, I have other end points in express that can send data to the front-end and if I redirect all GET request that end points does not work anymore. How should I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer by moving the app.get('*') below any other GET end points